# how get mac adress of used access points

Tags: java, android, networking

I'm using this code to get the saved info on wifi hotspots used by the phone:

```
 WifiManager w=(WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        ArrayList<WifiConfiguration> list=(ArrayList) w.getConfiguredNetworks();
        String data="";
        int i=0;

        if (list !=null && list.size()>0)
        {
           Log.d("WIFII:",network.toString());
}
```

Is it possible to get also mac adresse of those saved wifi networks ?
Thanks.

Comment: You CAN'T get mac adress from other devices. Only from your own device